# javascript regexp pattern definition

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help

I have a form feild I need to add validation to. The format of the value has to be specific. I want to define a regex pattern to handle it.

The format needs to  allow L123456

L = it has to be L which is the start of out skus
123456 = I need to confirm they are entering a 6 digit number.

thanks

Jeff

Comment: `/^L[0-9]{6}$/` ------

Comment: Sounds easy enough. What did you try that wasn't working for you?

Comment: Yes, a [very basic regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) can do that. Have you tried?

Comment: `<input pattern="L\d{6}">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "L123456"; 
/^L\d{6}$/.test(str)
```

The pattern uses the `^` to determine the strings starts with. `\d{6}` states 6 digits, and `$` means end of string. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for more info.